# Does Amazon Underground have any catches?

Tags: amazon-underground

The promise is of a library stocked with thousands of non-IAP games from popular developers.  But it sounds far too good to be true.

Is there any catch at all?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about an app-store rather than gaming.

Comment: The information you seem to be asking for is pretty clearly explained on the official website (http://amazon.com/underground)

Comment: I got curious... what place would be appropriate to ask this question, regardless if it's well explained on the official website or not? Let's say it's a Steam promotion or something else, where should I ask that kind of question?

Comment: that'd be a question for the [meta](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I agree with @vianna77. I think this question is completely valid. It has to do with a new platform for purchasing games. It's similar to if Steam started to offer free DLC or something on another platform.

Comment: I'm really curious now! I'm bringing it to meta because it really looks like a question that I would post here! I just checked all the other StackExchange groups and couldn't "best fit" this kind of question in any other place.

Comment: I just found a discussion about that [here](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/10675/google-play-store-off-topic) and posted a question to see of the veteran people think about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Amazon basically replaces the monetary value with a timer. For instance, instead of spending .99 on a purchase, you are able to "buy" this purchase every 24 hours for free.

Times and prices are different per app and per purchase. Just because something is .99, doesn't mean it's every 24 hours. It could be every 30 minutes or a one time buy sort of deal.

These apps are DIFFERENT than the original ones. For instance, you can own "Paplinko" and "Actually Free Paplinko". These will show up as 2 different apps in your account and can be installed separately.

[image]
[image]